# Work with windows service (WCF) in php

Tags: php, wcf, web-services, soap, wsdl

My boss give me a .net service link which said wrote with WCF.
I think the service wrote in wrong method because the service programmer said we don't have problem with this service when we use in asp.net but when I trying to use this service in PHP I have problem.

My code is :

```
$url = "http://<service url>?wsdl";

$param = new stdClass();
$param->type = "user";

$soap = new SoapClient($url);
$result = $soap->getPerm($param);
```

when I run my program I will get this message :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"'. in /home/work/soap.php:10
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://<service url>....', 'http://tempuri....', 1, 0)
#1 /home/work/soap.php(10): SoapClient->__call('getPerm', Array)
#2 /home/work/soap.php(10): SoapClient->getPerm(Object(stdClass))
#3 {main}
  thrown in /home/work/soap.php on line 10
```

I use google to solve my problem so I found this article :
http://www.binarytides.com/modify-soapclient-request-php/

When I extended the `SoapClient` to `SoapClientDebug` and use this I will get this message:

```
[Client] looks like we got no XML document in /home/work/soap.php:10
```

I'm really confused, I don't know how can I use windows service in php

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a bit late, but maybe this will be useful in any way.
From what You say Service seems to work fine.
Try this:
http://www.highonphp.com/fixing-soap-exception-no-xml

Or if You've actually managed to find out the solution, I'm curious what else can stand a problem.